# Multi variable calculus one-to-one and onto restriction

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$Let f:ℝ^2\Rightarrow ℝ$ be given by $f(x,y) = 3x^2+2y^2-5$

a) What is the domain and range of $f$

b) Restrict the domain so that $f$ is one-to-one on the new domain

c) Restrict the codomain so that $f$ is onto the new codomain

My answers

a) Since there is no restrictions, the domain of $f$ is $\lbrace(x,y)∈ℝ\rbrace$. Range is $\lbrace Z∈ℝ\;|\;Z≥5\rbrace$.

So b and c I'm a little confused about

b) For b I'm guessing that you just restrict it to $x>0$, but my friend is also is saying you have to restrict y so it's $y>0$ or $y<0$. I'm not entirely sure which works but if I think about it 2D wise, it's basically a parabola and if you restrict $x>0$, doesn't that automatically make it one-to-one since it will be continuously increasing?

c) For c I'm assuming you just have to make the codomain equal to the range so you restrict it to $\lbrace Z∈ℝ\;|\;Z≥5\rbrace$

Comment: You cannot restrict it just to $x>0$ because $f(x,y)=f(x,-y)$ so then it would not be one-to-one.

Comment: For c) see where the function takes minimal value.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Ahh, that makes sense. Then it would be $x>0$ and $y>0$ to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Wow.... Not the kind of phrasing I'd expect from a mathematician. For b) and c) you can use $\{(0,0)\}$ and $\left\{f(x,y)\colon (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\right\}$, respectively.

Comment: @GitGud For c) Wouldn't one answer, like I mentioned, be that I need to restrict the codomain equal to the range to make it onto? If I do that then wouldn't each value get mapped atleast once? Or am I thinking about it wrong

Comment: You are correct about (c).... except, you are mistaken about what the range is. For instance $f(0,0)$ is not in your proffered range. For $b$, it might help to realize that the codomain is one-dimensional, while the domain is two-dimensional. While it is possible for a function to match 2 dimensions to 1 injectively, such functions do not have simple expressions like this. So in this case, to have a 1-1 match between domain and codomain, you are going to need a 1 dimensional domain.

Comment: @HelloMellow You are correct, that is exactly what I did: $\left\{f(x,y)\colon (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\right\}$.